# import a large amount of json files to couchdb

Tags: php, json, couchdb, bulk

i 'm new to couchdb and managing a directory with json files (>300) that need to be imported on an existing database (this will be happenning e.g. every week). My question has basically 2 parts that are probably relative:

- Could someone recommend a high-level solution to my workflow? ( e.g. read the dir contents, use couchdb bulk api to post) I would favor involving php. I 've read several posts but i am not sure that they fit easily to my case.
- My Json files start and end with brackets [] and when i use

  ```
  curl -X PUT -d @name.json http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:5984/db/doc
  ```

  i get a fail due to "Document must be a JSON object"

  Is there a way to remove them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are posting to the `_bulk_docs` endpoint (e.g. `http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:5984/db/_bulk_docs`).

See [here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API#Modify_Multiple_Documents_With_a_Single_Request) for more info.